# Why is this catch all API route not working?

Tags: javascript, next.js

SO I been learning NextJS API routes and NodeJS recently, While I do know how to create dynamic routes now, I have some issues with a few things -

This is my `api/matches.js` file.

```
// Next.js API route support: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const response = await fetch(`https://exampleapi.com/?&token=# `)
  const jsonData = await response.json();
  res.status(200).json(jsonData);

}
```

Now, I have another dynamic route for this API which fetches the match by a match slug, So this file was called `/api/matches/[...matchslug].js`

```
export default async function handler(req, res) {
const  page  = req.query.matchslug
const response = await fetch(`https://examleapi.com/?search[slug]=${page}&token=# `)
const jsonData = await response.json();
```

While this dynamic route fetches the result of one so if I went `matches/exampelmatch`, I do get the results for the `examplematch`, However I'm looking to somehow implement it in a way that

```
matches/examplematch1/examplematch2
```

Returns the data from the `examplematch1 & examplematch2.`

I'm not sure if building something like is possible, But very interested.

Thank you for your time and patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `/api/matches/[...matchslug].js` example, the value of `matchslug` will always be an array.

Instead of passing the `page` variable directly into fetch, you can map over the values in the `matchslug` array and use `Promise.all` to request each resource.

It would look something like this (I haven't tested this):

```js
export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const promiseArray = req.query.matchslug.map(async (slug) => {
    const response = await fetch(`https://examleapi.com/?search[slug]=${slug}&token=# `)
    const jsonData = await response.json();
    return jsonData
  })
  const result = await Promise.all(promiseArray)
  res.status(200).json(result);
}
```